# Perl DBI when to close prepared statements

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi

I have an odd problem. On my dev computer I am getting errors. However on the live system the errors do not happen. If I fix the issues on dev the fixes cause problems in production.

It has to do with when I am closing prepared statements. On production I have to call finish after every fetch. If I do this on my dev system then the next execute of the statement will return undef, and there is nothing $dbh->errstr or in $DBI::errstr.

Any Idea where to even start with this one?

Here is a simple test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use Data::Dumper;

# Debug flag.
my $debug = 1;

#helper
sub getLoggingTime {

    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time);
    my $nice_timestamp = sprintf ( "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
                               $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
    return $nice_timestamp;
}

# Debug function.
sub dbg { if (! $debug) { return }; my $str = getLoggingTime() . " " . shift ; print STDERR $str }

# These are *the* date and time formats we use.
my $dateFormat = new DateTime::Format::Strptime('pattern' => '%F', 'locale' => 'en_NZ',             'time_zone' => 'Pacific/Auckland');
my $timeFormat = new DateTime::Format::Strptime('pattern' => '%T', 'locale' => 'en_NZ', 'time_zone' => 'Pacific/Auckland');

# Connect to the database.
my $dbconnect = *****removed**** || die 'No dbi_connection configured.';
my $dbusername = *****removed**** || die 'No dbi_username configured.';
my $dbpassword = *****removed**** || die 'No dbi_password configured.';

my $dbh = DBI->connect ($dbconnect, $dbusername, $dbpassword, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 }) ||
    die 'Cannot connect to database. ' . DBI::errstr;
my $test_sth = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT 
        ? as teststring, 
        GETDATE() as testdate
    ') || die 'Cannot prepare franchise name statement: ' . ($dbh->errstr ||$DBI::errstr || "")  . "\n";


##Attempt One
$test_sth->execute("Test string") || die "Could not execute test statement: " . ($dbh->errstr ||$DBI::errstr || "") . "\n";

my $result = $test_sth->fetchrow_hashref()
|| die "Cannot get result: " . ($dbh->errstr ||$DBI::errstr || "") . "\n";
$test_sth->finish();

my $testString = $result->{'teststring'};
my $testDate =  $result->{'testdate'};

dbg("testString = $testString, testDate = $testDate\n");


##Attempt Two 
$test_sth->execute("Test string") || die "Could not execute test statement: " . ($dbh->errstr ||$DBI::errstr || "") . "\n";

$result = $test_sth->fetchrow_hashref()
|| die "Cannot get result: " . ($dbh->errstr ||$DBI::errstr || "") . "\n";
$test_sth->finish();

$testString = $result->{'teststring'};
$testDate =  $result->{'testdate'};

dbg("testString = $testString, testDate = $testDate\n");

$dbh->disconnect();
1;
```

On dev I get :

> perl dbiTest.pl
>   2014/03/13 11:15:51 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:15AM
>   Could not execute test statement:

on Prod I get:

> dbiTest.pl 
>   2014/03/13 11:17:20 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:17AM
>   2014/03/13 11:17:20 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:17AM

If I comment the first $test_sth->finish(); 
On dev I get:

> perl dbiTest.pl 
>    2014/03/13 11:24:44 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:24AM
>   2014/03/13 11:24:44 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:24AM
>   on Prod I get:
>   perl dbiTest.pl 
>   2014/03/13 11:18:06 testString = Test string, testDate = Mar 13 2014 11:18AM
>   DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (51)
>   Message String: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending
>   DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (51)
>   Message String: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending

**UPDATE:**
Setting `$dbh->{syb_flush_finish} = 1;` allows the dev system to run finish and not break. 
This does fix my problem, but does not explain what is happening.

Comment: Is there a difference in perl version on dev machine and prod machine ? I have seen these kind of behaviour with different version of behaviours.

Comment: Yes there is prod is perl v5.10.1 and dev is v5.14.2

Comment: Is is very well possible that the difference in version leads to this error

Comment: This is only a style suggestion, but instead of building your timestamp, could instead use `use Time::Piece;  print localtime->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");`  [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) has been in perl core since 5.8

Comment: Perhaps DBD::Sybase was confused at some point about how finish is supposed to work. You might try reading off the select (until fetchrow returns null) instead of `finish` after the initial fetch.

Comment: Why are you using `finish` at all? It's very rare that you would need to call it explicitly, since the database driver will call it for you when you've fetched all results from a `SELECT`. If you only want one row, use `LIMIT 1` in your query; if your query already only returns one row, you shouldn't be calling `finish` at all.

Comment: This is not correct. On the new version yes you can get away with out calling finish. Bun on the older version you must fetch once more than the number of records to call finish automatically. It seems more correct to call finish. Also Sybase will throw warnings when disconnecting if you do not call finish. Warnings are not an option in the application.

Comment: @DanWalmsley How old is your version of DBD::Sysbase? According to the [changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/DBD-Sybase), v1.01 (released in 2003) included *"Automatically `finish()` statement handles if they are re-executed before all the rows have been fetched."*

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think you have explained this. I have 1.00 on production. If you want to put that as the answer I will tick that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of [`DBD::Sysbase`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aSybase) is way out of date. According to the [changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/DBD-Sybase), a fix was added in v1.01 (released all the way back in September, 2003!) to

> Automatically `finish()` statement handles if they are re-executed before all the rows have been fetched.

There was another fix in v1.06 (August, 2005) because `finish` sometimes failed to clean up the associated database handle. There have been many, many changes since v1.00, so upgrade to the latest version and drop the calls to `finish`.