# Perl Executing DBI execute in Loop

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I have a perl script which prepares a statement with params 1,2,3,4 using DBI interface .The prepare statement executes a stored procedure with 4 params.Then it runs a foreach loop and does execute

If the parameters are not right the stored procedure throws error and execute fails. I am interested in printing a warning and proceeding to next set of params.

After the first execute failure for an "invalid parameter", I get "Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending" as errmsg in SQL execute for subsequent loop iteration.

```
foreach my $file (@filelist)
{
  #..  get param1 , param2 , param3, param4 from $file
  unless ( dbh->execute($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4) )
  {
      #print some warning 
      next;
  }
}
```

How do I continue processing with this error?

These are the version I am using

```
>perl -MDBI -e 'DBI-> installed_versions;'
      Perl            : 5.010001    (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
      OS              : linux       (2.6.18-348.12.1.el5)
      DBI             : 1.609
      DBD::Sybase     : 1.15
      DBD::Sponge     : 12.010002
      DBD::SQLite     : 1.27
      DBD::Proxy      : install_driver(Proxy) failed: Can't locate  RPC/PlClient.pm in @INC
      DBD::Informix   : 2013.0521
      DBD::Gofer      : 0.011565
      DBD::File       : 0.37
      DBD::ExampleP   : 12.010007
      DBD::DBM        : 0.03
```

I added `{ RaiseError => 0, PrintWarn => 1, PrintError => 1 }`  in the connect as suggested by mekazu, (The code is exact same as yours mekazu ) but it is not helping still getting the same error.

In foreach  I get success, 
iteration 1 no error

iteration 2 gives a stored procedure error

> " Database execute failed. ERROR MESSAGE: Server message number=52001
>   severity=16 state=1 line=124 server=dev procedure=sp1 text=Data
>   Error:Invalid parameter: P1

iteration 3

> Database execute failed. ERROR MESSAGE: OpenClient message: LAYER =
>   (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (51) Server dev, database
>   dev Message String: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server
>   operation with results pending

iteration 4

> Database execute failed. ERROR MESSAGE: OpenClient message: LAYER =
>   (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (51) Server dev, database
>   dev Message String: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server
>   operation with results pending

Comment: Have you tried to sorround your `$dbh->execute($p1,$p2$"p3,$p4)` with `eval{ $dbh->execute(...); }or do{ #print some warning; next; }`?

Comment: I am getting same error - Database execute failed. ERROR MESSAGE:   OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (51)
Server dev, database dev   
Message String: Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending

Comment: How to clear this error. I am unclear if this is DBI or SQL error

Comment: It looks like that error is coming from the SQL server. Do you know where in  your program it is issued? Your code doesn't have any error handling through DBI. Is it something that DBI maybe does inside of `execute`? Are there any _at foo.pm line 123_ things in the error message that you didn't show? Adding example DDL with a `CREATE` of that stored procedure and/or table you are accessing, and a statement that you prepare to create this error as well as the Perl code that prepares would help. You can [edit] the question to add a [mcve].

Comment: What DBI version, what DBD driver and version?  This [error message suggests an old bug in the DBD::Sybase driver, fixed long ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22407578/132382)

Comment: `execute` is not a method of database handles as your code suggests, and `dbh` is either a bareword, a function, or a typo.  Can you please show us representative code that produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you disable `RaiseError` (default: false) when creating the handle. You can use `PrintWarn` (default: false) and `PrintError` (default: true) to save you doing it yourself:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password,
                { RaiseError => 0, PrintWarn => 1, PrintError => 1 });
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
foreach my $file (@filelist)
{
  #..  get param1 , param2 , param3, param4 from $file
  unless ( $sth->execute($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4) )
  {
      #warning already printed 
      next;
  }
}
```